# PowerShell error when attempting to create New-Object wia.imagefile

Tags: .net, powershell, dll, regsvr32

When attempting to use `New-Object` to create an object of type `wia.imagefile`, I get the following error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type [wia.imagefile]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

After a little research, I found that I needed to load the assembly.  I did so with the following command:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
```

Which returned:

```
GAC    Version   Location                                                                                                                                                       
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                       
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll
```

Now the `New-Object` cmdlet returns the following:

> New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered 
>       (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I've attempted to register the `System.Drawing.dll` with both 32-bit and 64-bit `regsvr32` commands.  When I do so I get the following error:

> The module "system.drawing.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
>
> Make sure that "system.drawing.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Comment: Remove the brackets in the declaration. `New-Object -ComObject wia.imagefile`. I can reproduce your error with the following `New-Object -ComObject [wia.imagefile]`

Comment: I'm not actually using brackets in the original command.  The original command is:

`$image = New-Object -ComObject wia.imagefile`